# CustomAsync task to refactor common calls

Tags: android, abstract-class

I have a classfile

### TMDB_Async.java

```
public class TMDB_Async {
  public class GetGenres extends CustomAsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {...}
  public class GetMovies extends CustomAsyncTask<Object, Void, String[][]> {...}
}
```

*note: it is implmenting:*

#### *CustomAsyncTask.java*

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask<T,T,T> extends AsyncTask<T,T,T> {...}
```

and then I'd like to use it .. something like:

### SomeActivity.java

```
new TMDB_Async.GetGenres(textView).execute(id);
```

But the *red-squiggly highlight* tells me that `TMDB_Async` is not an enclosing class. It invites me to do a static import, which it automatically makes as `xyz....TMDB_Async.*` and this doesn't fix the issue. If I specify `xyz...TMDB_Async.GetGenres` the last bit is all in red. If I remove `static` it also does not resolve my issue. So I'm doing something wrong here.

edit: I thought to make it a singleton, adding the code:

```
private static TMDB_Async mInstance = null;

private TMDB_Async(){
    mInstance = new TMDB_Async();
}

public static TMDB_Async getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        Class clazz = TMDB_Async.class;
        synchronized (clazz) {
            mInstance = new TMDB_Async();
        }
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

But this actually also does not resolve the problem.

How do I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner classes `GetGenres` and `GetMovies` need to be `static`.
Non-`static` inner classes can only be instantiated from a parent object.